# Paperclip resize gives different results locally vs on Heroku

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using the Paperclip gem to resize images. I have noticed some strange behaviour between the conversions locally in my development environment, and on the server at Heroku.

Specifically, when uploading the same source image to each environment, a resulting image size is different.

My config for the attached file in my model:

```
has_attached_file :image, :styles => { 
      :regular => "900x", 
      :retina => "1800x", 
      :thumb => "96x96#"
    }
```

The resulting file sizes for the :retina version are ~400k locally and ~1Mb on Heroku.

Is this the result of different imagemagick installs between the two environments? Is there some way to control this behaviour so that the resulting files will at least have consistency?

Comment: Are you trying on the same image?

Comment: Yep, as mentioned, using the same source image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
:convert_options => { :all => '-compress JPEG -depth 8'} # or another compression method
```

to standardize your resizing.

[Here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) you can find all options you can set in imagemagick.

Comment: That's cool thanks - still getting slightly different file sizes, but within 50kb or so now